# How to Filter Regular expression in MongoDB with F#

Tags: mongodb, f#

I've tried quite a few different ways of doing this and ultimately I would like to have multiple find filters together.

So - for example, one way would be like https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1228421/Dynamic-high-performance-Query-builder-for-MongoDB

Trying to build the following C# code in F#  ( and converting to my code )

```
Builders<CustomerGrid>.Filter.Regex(u => u.company,
               new BsonRegularExpression(companyColumnText + "*", "I"))
```

I have tried

```
let filter1 = Builders<PostDataItem>.Filter.Regex(fun n -> n.reference1,new BsonRegularExpression("1002\d{5}"))
```

and ( with brackets around field definition )

```
let filter1 = Builders<PostDataItem>.Filter.Regex((fun n -> n.reference1),new BsonRegularExpression("1002\d{5}"))
```

Another way of looking at it is to break down the parameters

```
    let fd: FieldDefinition<PostDataItem> = // ?? field = reference1
    let re: BsonRegularExpression = new BsonRegularExpression("1002\d{5}")
    let filter1 = Builders<PostDataItem>.Filter.Regex(fd,re)
```

It seems that if I could figure out how to build the field definition then it might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. The only problem I see is that [the LINQ expression has to have a return type of `Object`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_Regex_1.htm). This happens implicitly in C#, but in F# you have to explicitly cast it:

```
let filter1 =
    Builders<PostDataItem>
        .Filter
        .Regex(
            (fun n -> n.reference1 :> obj),
            BsonRegularExpression("1002\d{5}"))
```

(IMHO, this is just a bit of C# bias baked into their API. Hopefully they’ll fix it one day.)